Numbering in Hantzsch-Widman heterocycle nomenclature
At a lecture our professor gave this example (see image) for Hantzsch-Widman nomenclature of a monoheterocycle with multiple different heteroatoms. Our professor gave 4-Amino-5-sulfanyl-1,6,8,3,4-Dioxathiadiazonan-7-ol as the correct answer.
I do not understand the numbering though: Sure it starts with an oxygen which has highest priority of the heteroatoms. But then why does it take the longer way to the other oxygen, should not the other oxygen also receive the lowest possible locant? Wouldn't it be 8-Amino-9-sulfanyl-1,5,3,7,8-Dioxathiadiazonan-2-ol, where the 1,5 is lower than 1,6 for the oxygens? And the sulfur also has higher priority than the N, so why does take the way to the nitrogen? There must be some rule that I am missing. I know that the other prefixes and suffixes are far less important than the heterocycle, so I do not understand.
In other words: I am not sure if the sum of all locants decides the order, or just the higher priority locants going lower only when a decision can not yet be made.


Looking at this structure, I rather wonder to what products it would break down and how fast. Also names of compounds aren't proper nouns.

Ah the capitalization is how it is written in German, which is the language of the lecture.

Oh, in English they aren't proper nouns :)

Thanks to the answers given from Mathew and Buttonwood, I did some more literature search, and found that in fact, the numbering based on the lowest sum of locants is a rare exception used only by 1925 Patterson, as cited by Mathew before. Patterson writes:

Note 3. Lowest Numbers. The expression “lowest numbers,” as used in connection with the Rules, signifies the numbers yielding the smallest sum or, if the sums are equally small, those that include the lowest individual number or numbers. [1]

My professor insisted that the sum should never be used, and that is also what I was told many times before. So today I found an interesting publication [1954 Sumpter, Miller: Chemistry of Heterocyclic Compound, Chapter 11 Carbazole] where the authors express their frustration specifically about Patterson's different numbering scheme, and make it clear that the correct numbering is based not on the sum but on the lowest locant set, in the sense of considering the next priority atoms only if the higher priority atoms have equal priority in both directions. They write:

Unfortunately another system of numbering in which the nitrogen atom is numbered 5 was given authoritative support in 1925, although it was subsequently replaced by the system used herein. Indiscriminate use of the two systems, sometimes without designating which has been used, has led at times to some confusion. [2]


1. 1925, Austin M. Patterson: Proposed International Rules for Numbering Organic Ring Systems, J. Am. Chem. Soc., 47(2), 543–561 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01679a040).
2. 1954, Chapter 11 Carbazole. In Chemistry of Heterocyclic Compounds eds W.G. Sumpter and F.M. Miller, 70–109, (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470186572.ch2)

Note the resources page links to chemical nomenclature including IUPAC's Blue Book and G. P. Moss' html version. Reference 21 of rule P-22.2.2 leads to the 1982 revision here.

Hantzsch-Widman heterocycle nomenclature is the method initially introduced for the nomenclature of nitrogenous five— and six—membered heteromonocycles by Hantzsch (in 1887) and Widman (in 1888) independently (Ref. 1). These initial proposals underwent the usual discussion, refinement, and inevitable modification throughout the time, yet, the basic principle survived. One of these rules are as described in Ref. 2:

Rule 2: Choose as starting point a hetero atom of as high a group in the periodic table of the elements, and as low an atomic number in that group, as possible.

The Note for Rule 2 is stated as: The following order as determined by the above rule, includes the commonly occurring hetero atoms: $\ce{O \gt S \gt Se \gt Te \gt N \gt P \gt As \gt Sb \gt Si \gt Sn \gt Pb \gt Hg}$.
In addition Ref. 2 also states that:

Rule 3: With an atom of the preferred kind as 1, number around the ring in the way that gives to hetero atoms the lowest numbers possible.

Thus, in your given monocyclic heterocycle, the highest priority goes to $\ce{O}$ (Rule 2). Since you have two oxygens in your molecule, either can get the number one. Suppose if your instructor is correct, the numbering shoul be as shown in left structure:

If you are correct to give second oxygen the lowest number, it should look like right structure. Now, according to Rule 3 (like numbering in other carbocycles, etc.), heteroatoms should get the lowest numbers. According to left structure, the sum of numbers of heteroatoms is $(1+3+4+6+8=22)$. But, according to right structure, the sum of numbers of heteroatoms is $(1+3+5+7+8=24)$. Since $22 \lt 24$, the correct numbering is on left structure.
Let's see the other possible numbering, giving the second oxygen atom the priority:

Accordingly, the sum of numbers of heteroatoms in the left structure is $(1+3+4+6+8=22)$. But, that in the right structure is $(1+3+5+7+8=24)$. Since $22 \lt 24$, the correct numbering should on left structure (again).
But there are another rule in Ref. 2:

Rule 5: Of two or more numberings conforming to Rules 2-4,choose the one that gives to hydrogen atoms the lowest numbers possible.

Therefore, the correct numbering is on left structure with red numbers, meaning your instructor is correct as usual.
Note: Read Ref. 3&4 for more information on this matter.

References:

Commission on Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry, "Revision of the Extended Hantzsch-Widman System of Nomenclature for Heteromonocycles," Pure & Appi. Chem. 1979, 51, 1995—2003 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1515/iupac.51.0506).
Austin M. Patterson, "Proposed International Rules for Numbering Organic Ring Systems," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1925, 47(2), 543–561 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01679a040).
Austin M. Patterson, "The Nomenclature of Parent Ring Systems," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1928, 50(11), 3074–3087 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01398a034).
Seth C. Rasmussen, "The nomenclature of fused-ring arenes and heterocycles: a guide to an increasingly important dialect of organic chemistry," ChemTexts 2016, 2,  Article Number 16 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/s40828-016-0035-3).


Thank you very much for your detailed answer and the references! :) I had been thinking it likely is about the sum of the locants. However, it is almost never clearly stated that the sum is meant. In the 2016 Rasmussen I read "numbering of the ring begins with the most senior heteroatom and proceeds around the heterocycle to provide the lowest position numbers to the remaining heteroatoms." So does "provide the lowest position numbers" always mean the sum? I wish that was clearer.

I remember for the direction of numbering in open chains we were often reminded that the list of priorities is gone through step-by-step, and when a higher priority structure can get a lower locant then the direction is chosen without considering the lower priorities, which are only considered if not yet decided. So this is different here? Thank you again! :)

The sum gives you how low numbers you have given to remaining heteroatoms. Like I said, you have to consider other important rules as well when first rules don't work as we have done here. That clearly stated in Ref. 4.

I understand. However it is very important for me to be clear that it is nowhere stated that the sum should be used in what I found. Leaving that to be implied by the reader that "provide the lowest numbers" means "take the lowest sum of locants" seems dangerous? Especially if in other rules it is clearly said that it is not the sum. Things like this should be unmistakebly defined shouldn't they? Basically my whole question here boils down to a vague wording in the rules then, which could be avoided with a clear definition.
